# choose print some attrbute in json api

Tags: python

i want to print message "ขอเวลาปิดทำการ" in  "intent" attribute

```
{"intent": "ขอเวลาปิดทำการ",
  "category": "ติดต่อ",
  "confidence": 0.7881532327477858 }
```

but it cannot work

```
import requests
import json
message = input("What do you want")
def getbotnoi(message):
    undefined=message
    url = f"https://openapi.botnoi.ai/botnoi/ecommerce?keyword={undefined}"   
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTIwOTM5MjcsImlkIjoiNTJjYTJjODgtNDI2Ny00ZDEwLTkwNzktYmE4MGMxZWNhMzQ5IiwiaXNzIjoiZnloRHFJV1Npb3R4YmN3MkI4amZ5dUJBdUNHdFRLcm4iLCJuYW1lIjoiMTQzMy4wOCIsInBpYyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHJvZmlsZS5saW5lLXNjZG4ubmV0LzBoR1diUjVwYTVHSGhmS3pCcDdReG5MMk51RmhVb0JSNHdKMGxXR0h3dlFFMTJIVjRvWVJoVlNuOV9RMHh4SFZncE1VNEhHM3A1UWgxdyJ9.wfEGlqTBL1YQMsKWOEunptFk3mudSINF0ohdjTraCD0'}
    response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers).json()
    
    return (response.intent)
            
print(getbotnoi(message))
```

Comment: Don't post your secret key here

Comment: Ty. Can you help my question?